# How to show data when select and save

Tags: django

I am new in Django.
In this project, select machine name and operation number, after select, we need to click on save button, after button click, data should display in the form of table, when button click only.

Please tell me where I got wrong. Please.

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('upload/',views.upload,name='upload'),
   path('save',views.save_machine,name='save_machine'),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
def upload(request):
    machines = Machine.objects.all()
    return render(request,'usermaster/upload.html',{'machines':machines})

def save_machine(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      machine_name = request.POST.get('machine_name', '')
      operation_no = request.POST.get('operation_no')
      choiced_machine = Machine.objects.get(machine_name=machine_name, operation_no=operation_no)
      machines = Machine.objects.all()
      return render(request,'usermaster/upload.html',{'machines':machines,'choiced_machine':choiced_machine})
```

**template**
**upload.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'save_machine' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
       <select>
           <option>Select Machine Name</option>
           {% for machine in machines %}
           <option name="machine_name">{{ machine.machine_name }}</option>
           {% endfor %}
       </select>
       <br>
       <br>
       
       <select>
           <option>Select Operation Number</option>
           {% for machine in machines %}
           <option name="operation_no">{{ machine.operation_no }}</option>
           {% endfor %}
           </select>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <input type="submit" value="Save">
   </form>
   
   <tr>
       <td>{{choiced_machine.machine_name}}</td>
       <td>{{choiced_machine.operation_no}}</td>
   </tr>
```

**models.py:**

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    machine_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    operation_no = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.machine_name
```

when I clicked on save button, I got this error:

```
DoesNotExist at /save
Machine matching query does not exist.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/save
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Machine matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py, line 439, in get
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Manoj\\Desktop\\sample\\mysite5',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Thu, 13 Jan 2022 04:50:46 +0000
```

Comment: Move the data to be shown in tabular format to another html and redirect save_machine to that html page.

Comment: how to do this confused

Comment: Move <tr> tag from upload.html to new.html. In save_machine() function render new.html

Comment: i did that also but not working

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get machines before they're created. You need to use `Machine.objects.get_or_create()`

```
def save_machine(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      machine_name = request.POST.get('machine_name', '')
      operation_no = request.POST.get('operation_no')
      choiced_machine = Machine.objects.get_or_create(machine_name=machine_name, operation_no=operation_no)
      machines = Machine.objects.all()
      return render(request,'usermaster/upload.html',{'machines':machines,'choiced_machine':choiced_machine})
```

Comment: ntegrityError at /save
NOT NULL constraint failed: usermaster_machine.operation_no                                                               now showing above error

Comment: Hey please help me tell me where i got wrong